# angular-ui router - getting content from templateProvider into html and controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a `state` that needs to do some logic before it returns to a template, which took me a while to figure out but I finally learned about `templateProvider` and came up with this;

```
.state('home.read', {
    url: '/read/{id:u}',
    templateProvider: ($stateParams:ng.ui.IStateParamsService, $http:ng.IHttpService, $settings:ISettings) => {
        return $http({
            url: String.format('{0}/api/articles/read/{1}', $settings.uri(), $stateParams['id']),
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
})
```

That fetches the data I need from the server and filters it by credentials and such; It ensures that what I've gotten back is what I need.

So now I am confused - how can I get this to a controller and get the appropriate `.html` template to load up so I can use it?

The template is way too complicated to pass as a string. I really need it to exist as a static HTML file. I tried to use `templateUrl` but that didn't seem to work. Even if it did, I'm still unclear how I get the data to a controller - specifically because I need to attach it to the `$scope`.

Comment: templateUrl should work. did you get any errors in the console? could you upload plunkr?

Comment: `templateUrl` can get me to the HTML page, but I'm still not clear on how to get the results of the `templateProvider` into a meaningful variable on the `$scope` of whatever controller the HTML page uses

Comment: `templateProvider` is used to build dynamic templates on the fly. It should return a string formatted template (string representation of HTML).
If you want to **resolve** some data before the page loads then you should have a look at `resolve` option in the wiki: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: This is really good information. Thank you. So if I use `resolve`, can it access providers, services, etc? And if so, can it get the `$scope` of the controller the `<ui-view />` is inside?

Comment: I tried `resolve` last night but it can't seem to get `$scope` provider (or is `$scope` a service?)

Comment: You can't use `$scope` inside `resolve` (since this happens before $scope is initalized - before the viewmodel is initialized). maybe if you'll give me some more info then perhaps we can tackle this another way. what are you trying to achieve? load some data from backend and put it on the scope? be more specific.

Comment: The `ui-view` loads HTML that needs to bind to a model. The model is retrieved from the server. Therefore, I need the view to not load until after the model is loaded from the server and put on the `$scope` in the controller. The loaded model is also used in a different part of the HTML page that the view is a DOM child of, so I don't want to instantiate a new controller.

Comment: whenever you bind a model to a $scope, parent scopes won't have access to it unless you use $rootScope (bad practice). perhaps the loading and binding of the model should happen on the parent scope?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I have a controller (`IndexController`) and it has properties on the `$scope`. The HTML page is bound to many of these. When the route is triggered, I want to change one of these existing properties to have data retrieved from the server without making a new controller, or a new scope - but the template has a new DOM element that binds to them, so I need to delay the template loading until the data comes in from the server. I wanted to do this in the `state` so that it occurs when the route changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with typescript so I'll provide solution in plain js.

in config stage:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

 $stateProvider
  .state('read', {
   url: '/read/:id'
   controller: 'IndexController',
   resolve: {
    myResolvedData: function($stateParams, $settings, $http){
      return $http.get($settings.uri() + '/api/articles/read/' + $stateParams['id']);
    }
   }
  });
});
```

In `IndexController`:

```
.controller('IndexController', function($scope, ... , myResolvedData){
 //Bind resolved data to scope variable. template and controller will not load before
 //myResolvedData is resolved.
 $scope.data = {
  fromServer: myResolvedData
 };
});
```

Comment: Yeah! This is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you!

Comment: It's what we're here for :)